# Dit-on plutôt: « si l’envie te prend ou si l’envie t’en prend »?

Tags: constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Par exemple, dit-on « Tu peux corriger mes fautes si l’envie te prend » ou « Tu peux corriger mes fautes si l’envie t’en prend ? »

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux se disent à peu près dans les mêmes proportions mais la forme avec *en* est plus soutenue et plus présente à l'écrit. Le pronom optionnel *en* se rapporte à *de corriger mes fautes*.

En cas de vouvoiement, la forme sans *en* est peut-être plus courante.

> Vous pouvez corriger mes fautes si l'envie vous prend.

Pas de pronom s'il n'y a pas d'antécédent :

> Si l'envie te prend de corriger mes fautes, tu peux le faire.

On peut aussi dire:

- [...], si le cœur t'en dit. (soutenu)
- [...], si ça te dit. (courant)
- [...], si ça te tente. (courant)
- [...], si ça te branche. (relâché)
- [...], si ça te chante. (relâché, méprisant ou désapprobateur)

Answer (score 0):

On doit normalement utiliser le pronom « en » parce que la préposition avec laquelle  se construit «  prendre l'envie » est « de »  ([Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/prendre%20l%27envie)) ; comme dans la proposition « si l'envie te prend » la forme verbale serait utilisée sans un complément du nom, on pourrait trouver la construction anormale, mais il n'y a aucun principe qui assure cela, sauf qu'une énorme majorité des cas comprend le pronom « en » ([si l'envie t'**en** prend](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22si%20l%27envie%20t%27en%20prend%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)). Néanmoins, on trouve trois cas sans le pronom ([comparativement rare](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22si%20l%27%20envie%20te%20prend%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

([réf. 1, 1963](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_fin_d_une_r%C3%A9volution_1933_1942/63EfAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22si+l%27+envie+te+prend%22&dq=%22si+l%27+envie+te+prend%22&printsec=frontcover)) Ne peux-tu pas prier à la maison, si l'envie te prend ? Ce n'est pas la même chose, mon fils. Tu ne peux plus me comprendre . Cependant, quand tu étais petit, tu aimais bien quand notre pope vieux-croyant venait officier dans notre ...

([réf. 2, 2005](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Guirlandes_fan%C3%A9es/-BUTAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22si+l%27+envie+te+prend%22&dq=%22si+l%27+envie+te+prend%22&printsec=frontcover))  Plaisante, si l ' envie te prend, avec les autres bêtes de la terre ; épargne-moi cette honte, car je pourrais bien te mettre en pièces ! C'est en ces termes que Moustique s'adressa un jour à Éléphant.

([réf. 3, 2014](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cr%C3%A9ation_d_un_monde_le_ma%C3%AEtre_du_temps/D0oPCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22si+l%27+envie+te+prend%22&pg=PT76&printsec=frontcover)) Tu as le droit d'avoir des jours de repos, cela te donne aussi le droit d'être totalement indépendante si l'envie te prend. Tu as donc le droit de te faire cuire les choses que tu aimes comme tu les aimes.